# How to launch Market App with market URL through App Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, google-play

I want to launch my app's details page using market application by clicking a image button on the app widget. I tried it using following code after referring this link http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market.android.com/details?id=com.abc.abcdef"));
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rateme, pendingIntent);
```

But everytime I clicked on the image button on the widget I get following message in logcat

> Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=market.android.com/details?id=com.abc.abcdef flg=0x10000000
>   bnds=[22,243][166,385] } from pid -1

without any success of launching market application. 
If any one have a solution for this problem, please share it with me.
Thanks,
SKU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your `setData()`:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.abc.abcdef"));
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#OpeningDetails

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I did not realize I was using URL in a wrong way. It worked.